# How to send email as a specific "Support" admin user in a custom workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I've created a custom workflow that sends emails to certain Contact Entities. I want the `From` field to be the "support" user (and email) that we've created in CRM, so that any replies would go to the correct place.

However, I don't know how to get that to work. Here's what I have:

```
var fromParty = new ActivityParty
{
    PartyId = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid("what goes here?")),
};
```

How do I get the Guid of the User that I want to send the emails as?
Is this even the correct way to go about what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out this bit of documentation from the CRM SDK on adding an input parameter to your custom workflow assembly that allows to to choose the system user via a lookup when configuring the workflow step (like Daryl suggests).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327842.aspx#AddingInput

Answer (score 1):

You'll either have to lookup the user id using the `SystemUser` entity, or pass it into the workflow activity.